# How to generate PWL or pulse in verilog without using clock

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am working on a piece of code in which I need to generate output as per the condition-

`1. if input is X/Z output should be X.
 2. if input is 0 output should be 0 with a delay of 0.75us.
 3. if input is 1 output should be 5 high going pulses of 1.5us with 50% duty cycle 
    with a delay of 0.75us.`

I am confused How to write it in verilog?

Comment: What is a *PWL*? Is this for a testbench or design?

Comment: @dave_59 PWL is piece wise linear for my application, its a pattern which we can define in circuit files as (t1 v1 t2 v2 ....) it means that at time t1 the pattern should take value v1, at time t2 it should be v2... so on).

Comment: You can write it in Verilog without clock but you can **not convert that to actual hardware**. Also what happens if the input changes while your output is still busy from a previous input?

Comment: @Oldfart in that case it should show the result based on the new input condition. And yes its for testing purposes, I don't need it for synthesis.

Comment: Without your last comment *"it should show the result based on the new input condition"* it is not too difficult to write such a code using #<delay> statements but that new requirement makes it complicated. I would start with make a local1.33MHz clock and write an FSM but without using a clock I leave the problem to you.

Comment: @Oldfart how will we code it if the last condition I gave wasn't there?

Comment: I do not write code in answers. Read up on the Verilog delay **#** operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SystemVerilog's `fork/join_none` for this

```
logic in, out;

    always begin
               fork 
                  case (in)
                    0: out <= #0.75us 0;
                    1: repeat (5) begin
                           #0.75us out <= 1; 
                           #0.75us out <= 0; 
                          end
                    default: out <= 'x;
                   endcase
                join_none;
                @in
                disable fork; // kill repeat loop if still active
             end
```